# Setting multiple if statements correctly

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have difficulty to set proper nested `if statement` in a user-defined function.

My sample data is like this

```
test <- data.frame(x=rev(0:10),y=10:20)

if_state <- function(x,y) {
  if (x==min(x) && y==max(y)) {
    "good"
  } else if (max(x)/2==y[which(y==15)]/3) {  # to find when x=5 and y=5 condition if it is true set class to "y==5"
    "y==5"
  }
    NA
}

   > test
    x  y
1  10 10
2   9 11
3   8 12
4   7 13
5   6 14
6   5 15
7   4 16
8   3 17
9   2 18
10  1 19
11  0 20

library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(class = if_state(x,y))

    x  y class
1  10 10    NA
2   9 11    NA
3   8 12    NA
4   7 13    NA
5   6 14    NA
6   5 15    NA
7   4 16    NA
8   3 17    NA
9   2 18    NA
10  1 19    NA
11  0 20    NA
```

I don't know why the if statement is not working correctly?
The question is what is the base R function that work same as dplyr's `case_when` ? please see the comments below.

So the expected output

```
    x  y class
1  10 10    NA
2   9 11    NA
3   8 12    NA
4   7 13    NA
5   6 14    NA
6   5 15    y==5
7   4 16    NA
8   3 17    NA
9   2 18    NA
10  1 19    NA
11  0 20    good
```

Comment: After the if statement, you are returning NA. You need to explicitly return, e.g. `return("good")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R functions return the last value evaluated evaluated during their invocation, even without an explicit call to `return` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not) for more detail); so, where `NA` is the last value evaluated in your `if_state` function (as it's outside the `if-else if` control flow, and so will always be evaluated), it will always return `NA`, even when the `if` and `else if` conditions are true. For your function to work as you expect, you need to move `NA` into an else statement:

```
if_state <- function(x,y) {
  if (x == min(x) && y == max(y)) {
    "good"
  } else if (max(x)/2 == y[which(y == 15)]/3) {
    "y==5"
  } else {
    NA 
  }
}
```

Note that when using dplyr, testing for multiple conditions to determine a return value is often more succinctly accomplished with `case_when`:

```
test %>% mutate(class = case_when(
  x == min(x) && y == max(y) ~ "good",
  max(x)/2 == y[which(y == 15)]/3 ~ "y == 5",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
))
```

**Edit:** based on OP's clarification and eipi10's help, here is the final function:

```
if_state = function(x, y) {
  case_when(x == min(x) && y == max(y) ~ "good", 
            x == max(x)/2 & y/3 == 5 ~ "y==5", 
            TRUE ~ NA_character_)
}
```

Comment: It looks like `max(x)/2 == y[which(y == 15)]/3` is always TRUE, so the result will be `"y==5"` for any rows that don't satisfy the first condition. Maybe the OP actually wanted something like `x==max(x)/2 & y/3==5 ~ "y==5"`?

Comment: @cmaher Thank you for explicit answer. wheh I run the your new `if_state` I am getting all class values to be `y==5` ??

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: @cmaher, How could `max(x)/2 == y[which(y == 15)]/3` be true always. 
There is only one row that satisfies this right ?

Comment: @Alexander I had copied the conditions from the question (the `if-else` statement also always returns `"y == 5`` for the test data). Would you mind explaining your expected output?

Comment: @Alexander the condition in eipi10's comment appears to give your intended result? (e.g. if you change the `case_when` to `mutate(class=case_when(x == min(x) && y == max(y) ~ "good", x == max(x)/2 & y/3 == 5 ~ "y==5", TRUE ~ NA_character_))`

Comment: `max(x)/2` returns 5 for every row in the data frame. `y[which(y == 15)]/3` returns 5 for every row in the data frame. So the condition being evaluated is `5==5` which is always TRUE.

Comment: @cmaher sure. The function should catch the multiple conditions at once. So when `max(x)/2` and the `y` value divided by `3` is equal to `5`, set class to  `y==5`. That is it!

Comment: @cmaher the question is i cant use case_when because I have too many conditions that should be defined in `function`.

Comment: @cmaher I thought your modified `if_state` should be solving the issue without `case_when` ?

Comment: You can put the `case_when` statement inside the `if_state` function, just as you would for the `if` statements. Then you would do `mutate(class = if_state(x,y))`, just as in your original code.

Comment: @eipi10 actually my original question than would be what is the r base function that replicates `case_when` ? maybe `with` ??

Comment: You could do nested `ifelse` statements or you could use subsetting, but why not just use `case_when`?

Comment: @eipi10 I can use that but I am still not familiar with it. Could you send a solution when `case_when` used in function ?

Comment: Wrap @cmaher's answer in a function call (and I've changed the second condition as well): `if_state = function(x,y) {case_when(
  x == min(x) && y == max(y) ~ "good",
  x == max(x)/2 & y/3 == 5 ~ "y==5",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
)}`